# why am I getting one line of numbers?

Tags: python

```
num = int(input('Enter a number:'))

for i in range(0, num, 1):
    for j in range(0, i):
        print(num, end =" ")

for i in range(num, 0, -1):
    for j in range(0, i):
        print(num, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 8):

Because `end=" "` overrides the default behaviour which is to print a newline `\n`.

The effect of this is to separate each number by a space  rather than a newline `\n`.

Comment: I was told to use this to print an half diamond of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This line `print(num, end=" ")` will only print the initial number `num`. Are you perhaps wanting one of your iterating numbers (i or j)?

Also `end=" "` suppresses the normal behavior of appending a `\n` to the end of the print statements.

---

**EDIT**

Going by your comment, I think you want this (assuming `num=3`):

```
3 
3 3 
3 3 3 
3 3 
3
```

Which you can get by adding print statements that only provide newlines like so:

```
def diamond(number):
    for i in range(0, number, 1):
        for j in range(0,i):
            print(number, end=" ")
        print("")

    for i in range(number, 0, -1):
        for j in range(0, i):
            print(number, end=" ")
        print("")
```

If you want each row to have a number equal to row size, change the `number` in the print statements to `i`.

---

**EDIT 2**

Do you mean you want this?

```
Enter a number:5

1 
2 2 
3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 
4 4 4 4 
3 3 3 
2 2 
1
```

The reason the user input from before won't work is probably due to the ordering of the python file or how you called the method. If you write this into a `.py` file and run it through IDLE you can get that.

```
def diamond(number):
    for i in range(0, number, 1):
        for j in range(0,i):
            print(i, end=" ")
        print("")

    for i in range(number, 0, -1):
        for j in range(0, i):
            print(i, end=" ")
        print("")


num = int(input('Enter a number:'))
diamond(num)
```

If you mean you want

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2
1
```

then you need to replace those i's with `j+1` (remember, the range is starting at 0).

Comment: I'm trying to print a half diamond of numbers, I was told to put end="" in my print statement but I wasn't sure why I had to.

Comment: So print("") provides a newline?

Comment: @nummy Yes. What it's actually doing is printing an empty string with a newline character at the end, which ends up just a newline character. When you don't override the end character of the print method python will automatically append a newline character to whatever is printed.

Comment: Okay that helps, but Now I am confused about user input I thought my user input looked fine before, but I keep getting this Enter a number:4
4 
4 
4 
4 
4 
4 
4 
4 
4 
4 
4 
4 
4 
4 
4 
4 
None or this with no input >>> 
>>> 
>>> ???? why is that will the newline not print the row size i changed number in the print statement to i but i just get the vertical line of numbers. basically why wont my user input from before work on this code or do i have the syntax wrong for user input?